# Cannot return String from @RestController method

Tags: spring, rest, java-8, mybatis, primitive-types

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.4.5, MyBatis 3.5.6 and Java 8. When trying to return a String from a `@RestController`, an obscure error shows up in the returned `HttpErrorResponse`.

The method tries to obtain the value via MyBatis, i.e., a method in a DAO object that acts as a `@Mapper`.

**My controller method:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/myAPI")
public class MyController{
    @Resource
    private MyService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "myString")
    public String getBillingCompany() {
        return this.service.getDAO().getMyString();
    }
}
```

**My DAO:**

```java
@Repository
@Mapper
public interface MyDAO{
    String getMyString();
}
```

**...and the MyBatis mapper:**

```xml
<mapper namespace="com.package.MyDAO">
    <select id="getMyString" resultType="String">
        SELECT 'My desired result' FROM A_TABLE
    </select>
    ...
</mapper>
```

**The HttpErrorResponse:**

```json
HttpErrorResponse: {
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/api/myAPI/myString",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/myAPI/myString",
    "error": {
        "error": {  SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 2
                    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
                    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:18158:51)
                    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:21266:35)
                    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:74037:33)
                    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:21265:40)
                    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:21033:51)
                    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:21348:38)
                    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:22516:18)
                    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:22553:25)
                 },
        "text": "My desired result"
    }
}
```

Nonetheless, if I ask the controller and the DAO methods to return an `int`, it all works flawlessly.

Due to this, I suspected that the issue has to do with non-primitive types "namespacing", so I've tried to set a `typeAlias` in the MyBatis configuration, to no avail:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="java.lang.String" alias="String"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>
```

Anyways, I'm under the impression that both MyBatis and Spring should be already smart enough to know what a `String` is. I've successfully returned collections of objects (`Map`s and `List`s) and POJOs in the past.

Any ideas on what I'm lacking or not seeing? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
The only thing that has worked for me so far is similar to what @emeraldjava proposed. I've built a wrapper upon an existing one in a dependency, fetching the `data` in my Front:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/myAPI")
public class MyController{
    @Resource
    private MyService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "myString")
    public Result<String> getBillingCompany() {
        return new Result<>(this.service.getDAO().getMyString());
    }
}
```

```java
public class Result<T> extends ServiceResult {
    public Result(T data) {
        this.setData(data);
    }
}
```

The already existing wrapper in a dependency:

```java
public class ServiceResult {
    private Object data;

    ...

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m not familiar with mybatis, but just trying to rule things - Do you have a sample of a string returned by getMyString()? I would imagine that the StringHttpMessageConverter kick in and write out the string as text/plain, but that error payload is interesting. Curious if there is a stack trace and curious on what would happen if you add produces text plain to the GetMapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you update your Controller method to a ResponseEntity which wraps the string.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/myAPI")
public class MyController{
    @Resource
    private MyService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "myString")
    public ResponseEntity getBillingCompany() {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(this.service.getDAO().getMyString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it without success. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the table you're querying has multiple rows, so the result of your query will be a List of string, containing "My desired result" on each element, in which the size of the list is equal to the number of rows in the table. In order to force a single result, just change the query to:

```
<select id="getMyString" resultType="String">
        SELECT MAX('My desired result') FROM A_TABLE
</select>
```

Comment: Tried it, still obtaining the same result :(

Comment: Everything looks correct. Since you said you tried with an integer and it worked, maybe it could be a problem of using old dependencies? i would try reloading them, and rebuilding the project